# Prove that $A$ is positive semidefinite iff $\alpha \geq 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

> Given a symmetric matrix $n\times n$
>
> $$A_{i,j} = \begin{cases} \alpha & \text{ if } i=j\\ 1 & \text{ if } i \neq j \end{cases}$$
>
> Prove that $A$ is positive semidefinite iff $\alpha \geq 1$.

---

I managed to show that by assuming $\alpha < 1$ we get a contradiction that A is positive semidefinite but the second side I thought maybe using Sylvester's criterion?

Comment: Hint: Write $A = (\alpha-1)I + ee^T$, where $e$ is the vector of all $1$s. Then use the definition of positive semidefiniteness

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Can you find the eigenvalues of the all-ones matrix? If so, then shift them by $\alpha-1$ and you have the eigenvalues of $A$.